# Custom styling of Add This share plugin modal

Tags: css, modal-dialog, customization, addthis

I'm using the [Add This plugin](http://www.addthis.com/) for a simple sharing widget, and I need to apply custom CSS to style the modal according to design specifications. I am trying to use the attribute ui_use_css ([documentation here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381221-optimizing-addthis-performance#nocss)) to prevent Add This from adding its own CSS so that the modal will inherit the styles I create. I did this like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var addthis_config = {
        ui_use_css: false
    };
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=baaqmd" async="async"></script>
```

The problem is that when I add this config attribute, the plugin no longer inserts the widget buttons into the DOM. Has anyone used this plugin and added custom styles to customize the modals that pop up? If so, what method did you use? Why would this attribute keep the plugin from functioning?

Comment: I've try to reproduce what you have experienced, and the code seems to hide the toolbar, but showing the button: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEWZGW. i hope it would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

Preventing our CSS isn't supported in the dashboard configuration tools. Your best bet is to use your own CSS and the !important flag to override any rules that are too sticky.

Note that CSS overrides aren't officially supported by AddThis.